# Where Clause - Between Condition Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, where-clause, between

I'm trying to work on my query below on I have most of it right, but for some reason my BETWEEN condition is not working when trying to filter out the dataset...it doesnt filter it at all. Can anyone take a look at my code below and let me know what I'm doing wrong...or maybe even suggest an alternative way to filter out the records from July to end of September?

```
SELECT  A.[Name] AS ResourceName,
    A.[ID] AS ResourceID,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.[STRT_Date],101) AS StartDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.[END_Date],101) AS EndDate,
    CASE WHEN A.[END_Date] > A.[STRT_Date] THEN C2.[DY_OF_CAL_NUM] - C1.[DY_OF_CAL_NUM] 
         WHEN A.[END_Date] IS NULL and A.[STRT_Date] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[DY_OF_CAL_NUM] - C1.[DY_OF_CAL_NUM]
         WHEN A.[END_Date] = A.[STRT_Date] THEN 1
    END AS AgeCalendar
FROM    [Report] AS A       
    INNER JOIN [Dim] AS B 
    ON A.[ID] = B.[ID]  
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DT_DIM] AS C1 
    ON CAST(A.STRT_Date AS DATE) = C1.[CAL_DT]      
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DT_DIM] AS C2 
    ON CAST(A.END_Date AS DATE) = C2.[CAL_DT]       
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DT_DIM] AS C3 
    ON CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) = C3.[CAL_DT]
WHERE   1 = 1
AND     A.[STRT_Date] BETWEEN '07/01/2016' AND '09/30/2016'
AND     A.[Name] like '%S-Info%'
OR      A.[Name] like '%S-Dep%'
OR      A.[Name] like '%S-Can%' 
OR      A.[Name] like '%S-Doc%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `Or` operators with `()`:

```
WHERE A.[STRT_Date] BETWEEN '07/01/2016' AND '09/30/2016'
AND (A.[Name] like '%S-Info%'
     OR A.[Name] like '%S-Dep%'
     OR A.[Name] like '%S-Can%' 
     OR A.[Name] like '%S-Doc%')
```

What currently happens is that if a record has a `Name` that is like `'%S-Doc%'`, even if it is not between the dates it will be selected. By wrapping all the variations of the valid `Name`s you say that it has to be between the dates and "one of the following conditions"

Comment: Thank you...I knew it had to be something small. Appreciate you!